# VueJS | Method "watch" has type "object" in the component definition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-storefront

Currently I have following Watches in `Product.vue` file

```
watch: {
    isOnline: {
      async handler (isOnline) {
        if (isOnline) {
          const maxQuantity = await this.getQuantity();
          this.maxQuantity = maxQuantity;
        }
      }
    },
    isMicrocartOpen: {
      async handler (isOpen) {
        if (isOpen) {
          const maxQuantity = await this.getQuantity();
          this.maxQuantity = maxQuantity;
        }
      },
      immediate: true
    },
    isSample (curr, old) {
      if (curr !== old) {
        if (!curr) {
          console.log('send the updateCall', curr);
          // this.updateProductQty(this.product.qty);
          pullCartSync(this);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

but I am getting this following error (Vue Warn) in console

> [Vue warn]: Method "watch" has type "object" in the component definition. Did you reference the function correctly?

[image]

I'm not sure why i am getting this error, as the syntax i am using seems to be correct, and its even functioning right.

Any suggestions why its giving this warning in error console?

---

**Update:**

Location where i have used the watch in vue page.

[image]

Comment: Do you have method named `watch` in `methods` object?

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov, No its after the methods closing braces. I have added the screenshot for where i am using it.

Comment: and if you remove `async/await`?

Comment: Can you show the full definition of your object with removed method bodies?

Comment: Do you have any mixins that add `watch` method somehow?

Comment: You have something like this `methods: { watch: {} }` in the component definition. That's the error. `methods` should only contain methods, not objects

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have something like `methods: { watch: {} }` in your component definition. That's why vue is complaining. That might be added by a `mixin` as well.